# partial order and truth value

Tags: order-theory

please,give a formula Q with free variables such that for any partial order 
  (
  A
  ;
  ≤
  ;
  -)

we have that [Q]=1 iff [z] is a join of [x] and [y]

Answer (score 1):

HINT: I’m assuming that $[x]$ is the interpretation of $x$ in the partial order, while $[Q]$ is the truth value of $Q$. You want a formula $Q(x,y,z)$ that says that $z$ is the join of $x$ and $y$, but you have only the order $\le$ to work with: you don’t have the join operation. If $a,b,c\in A$, $c$ is the join of $a$ and $b$ precisely when $c$ is the least upper bound of the set $\{a,b\}$. This means two things:

- $c$ is **an** upper bound for $\{a,b\}$; and
- $c$ is the **least** upper bound for $\{a,b\}$: if $u$ is any upper bound for $\{a,b\}$, then $c\le u$.

Your formula $Q(x,y,z)$ therefore has to say that $z$ is an upper bound for $x$ and $y$ **and** that it’s the least of the upper bounds. Just translate these requirements into logical formalism, and you’ll have $Q(x,y,z)$.

Comment: Q=[P(z,c) iff P(x,c) and P(y,c)]  P relation symbol with less than equal.  is it formula possible? c is constant

Comment: @1214: No, that won’t work: you have no constant available to use. The formula $P(x,z)\land P(y,z)$ says that $z$ is an upper bound for $x$ and $y$; now you need to add something to it that says that $z$ is their **least** upper bound. The added expression will require a universal quantifier.

Comment: if [(P(x,z) and P(y,z)) and (P(x,u) and P(y,u))] then z less than equal u ?

Comment: @1214: You’re getting there, but the only free variables of $Q$ should be $x,y$, and $z$: $u$ has to be a bound variable, so it needs to be in the scope of some quantifier. (Also, that last bit is $P(z,u)$.)

Comment: Also,in my text definition of join :one say that z is a join of x and y if for all c∈A we have z≤c if and only if x≤c and y≤c.

Comment: @1214: Okay; that’s equivalent to the definition that I had in mind. The final formula $Q$ will be a little different if you use that one, but the basic idea remains the same. Notice that *for all*: $Q(x,y,z)$ should say $\forall u(\text{something})$.